# How to un-italicize text in equations/math

Tags: equations, italic

I have a question about text which is within an aligned equation. I am happy with the way my equations are aligned, I would like to make some of the text not italicized.
In the code, I would like to have "where" unitalicized.
Also, I would like to align the 2nd equals signs with each other, but I'll tackle that later.

(MWE provided by [sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano))

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Aligning equal signs. Example.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y_{destr} &  = nL\lambda/2d, \text{where}\,\, n= \pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \ldots \\
y_{constr} & = nL\lambda/d, \text{where}\,\, n = 0, \pm1, \pm2, \pm3, \ldots\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Load the **amsmath** package and use the **\text{un-italized text}** command

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned the `\text` macro is the tool for that. I think you will also want to use `\mathrm` (or `\text`) for the subscripts of the `y`s. And use `\dots` instead of `...`.

For the alignment, the `alignat` environment can help you align at both equals sign.

Further, are the `(1)` and `(2)` intended to be equation numbers? If so, don't write them out manually, just use the math environment without a `*` at the end, they are numbered automatically.

Finally, don't end the last line of `align` (or similar) with `\\`, that will give you unwanted vertical space after the math display (and an extra number for numbered equations).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
y_{\mathrm{destr}} &= nL\lambda/2d, \text{ where } & n &= \pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \dots \\
y_{\mathrm{constr}} &= nL\lambda/d, \text{ where} & n &= 0, \pm1, \pm2, \pm3, \dots 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

As Sam Carter suggested, it might be better to align at `where` instead of the second `=`. Alternatively, if the second `n` was a wider symbol/longer expression than the first `n`, then you can align at both `where` and `=`. It wont make a difference in this case though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Align at where:
\begin{alignat}{2}
y_{\mathrm{destr}} &= nL\lambda/2d, &&\text{ where }  n = \pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \dots \\
y_{\mathrm{constr}} &= nL\lambda/d, &&\text{ where }  n = 0, \pm1, \pm2, \pm3, \dots 
\end{alignat}
Align at where and =:
\begin{alignat}{3}
y_{\mathrm{destr}} &= nL\lambda/2d, &&\text{ where } & n &= \pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \dots \\
y_{\mathrm{constr}} &= nL\lambda/d, &&\text{ where } & n &= 0, \pm1, \pm2, \pm3, \dots 
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest a second version with the "where" aligned?  (You bet my by 20 seconds :)

Comment: @samcarter Working on it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Mine is less detailed, and I thought it went well as well. I vote your answer obviously.

Comment: Just a minor addition: I don't see why one should, at least in most cases, use \mathrm over \text. I think the fact that spaces are ignoted is for beginners rather irritating or confusing. In addition, if you have a sans serif surrounding text, then \text will recognize this. But I am not a pro like you guys.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'm certainly not a pro, so I wont be arguing firmly on finer points of typesetting. I did only use `\mathrm` for the subscript though.